# debian, wxWidgets, compile: got library instead of executable

Tags: linux, wxwidgets, executable

On a new notebook just installed Debian, g++, codeblocks, wxWidgets, DialogBlocks ...
After compiling a GUI program (wxWidgets) I get a library as result instead of an executable.
Same source on another box with Debian works fine.
Compiling a simple console program on the new box works fine.
I'm somewhat confused.
Any idea?

Comment: how do you know it is not executable but the library? what version of the library did you install? Did you build it yourself or grab it from the repo? Can you build and run the minimal sample?

Comment: wxWidgets 3.1.2, DialogBlocks 5.15.1, tryed both GTK2 und GTK3

Comment: compilation runs fine in Codeblocks or Dialogblocks but not from the file browser.

Comment: file browser thinks it's a library

Comment: Build the library myself (as usual since years). My sample is even simpler than minimal. Just another hello world.

Comment: Just trying to reproduce the problem in a virtual machine.
BTW, THX igor

Comment: what does the Terminal thinks?

Comment: does not execute. Not at my workplace currently.. THX

Comment: Some analyzis got me more insight. There a 2 problems, possibly not related to each other.

My program did not start without a terminal. But it (most likely) did within a terminal. The new Debian installation missed a library for png files. My program issued an error message and terminated. That takes a couple of milliseconds - hard to see on the display.

After installing the missing library, my program works fine using GTK2. Using GTK3 is still a problem which I will resolve later.

Comment: But file browser insist my programs are libraries, not executables. "ELF 64-bit LSB shared object".

Here 2 programs, locale and env, in /usr/lib.

~$ file /usr/bin/locale
/usr/bin/locale: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked,  ...

~$ file /usr/bin/env
/usr/bin/env: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, ...

My programs require to be started from a terminal. Seams GUI programs (at least) don't need this or could have the terminal invisible. How to achive that, how to get an executable as for locale?

Comment: so even for GTK2 you can't start the program from the file browser? Now for GTK+3, do you have a separate wxWidgets build that link against GTK3? You absolutely have to build wxWidgets binaries that will link against GTK+3 and rebuild you software with the newly created wx binaries.

Comment: now for the file browser - it may some OS issue/security problem. As a test - can you build the minimal sample and try to run it from the file browser? With both GTK+2 and GTK+3?